# Javascript: MutationObserver / detect global stylesheet rule changes

Tags: javascript, css, events, stylesheet, mutation-observers

I've been stuck for the past couple of days, trying to figure out a way to detect / trigger a global CSS change event. Yes, a global one (so not one which is set by the element itself **(style="background:red;" for example)**, but is set in a seperate **.css** file).

I've tried using **MutationObserver** (as my event catcher / instance), but this instance doesn't seem to pick up my fulfilling. The most logical way instead (according to my knowledge), would be to store all the CSS-rules (of the target file) and set an interval which will check for any updates (comparing the list stored) every x seconds. But ofcourse, this wouldn't be such a good practice since this is a waste of memory.

Any suggestions? They would be appericiated a lot!

Comment: It might be helpful to see an example of that global CSS change, how exactly that change occurs e.g. an `<link>` element is added in document's HEAD or is it because of a media query, etc.

Comment: @wOxxOm This may sound really really, but really stupid. But i'm developing my own **'developer tools'** which would at long last be embeddable in a JavaScript application. How this 'change' occurs is simply by real-time editing the CSS file in the developer tools (chrome / firebug, etc) nor real-time editing the CSS file from the 'styles' tab (which actually does the same as the previous mentioned).

Comment: I mean, even if you edit that file, how exactly the page will update its linked style sheet? Because there's no built-in auto-update feature, so my question implies you can probably detect that event. Anyway, MutationObserver definitely won't detect a change in CSS rules.

Comment: You're right. Editing a CSS file won't be updated in the current DOM. I'm basically trying to figure out if an element still has a pseudo-element attached. That, i'm currently doing by **window.getComputedStyle($(currentNode)[0], ':after').getPropertyValue("content")**, which basically tells me if the attribute 'content' is found on the given node in the :after selector. But since pseudo-elements aren't part of the DOM. I have to find / stimulate a way to catch these appearings / dissapearings (so basically if they are being removed / added, that something catches this event).

Comment: Well, Chrome extension can use [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.onResourceContentCommitted](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#event-onResourceContentCommitted) event listener, so I guess FireFox might have something similar as well...

Comment: @wOxxOm First of all, thanks for your time. This extension is very usefull, but I think it won't fulfill my browser support needed. I'm trying to find a solution for IE > 9+, all of chrome, all of firefox, all of safari and android. Do you have any other suggestions which are usefull? Thanks **- EDIT: I found a way in order to retrieve the latest CSSRuleList, which would help me a lot. So now, I have one question left. Is it possible (since this RuleList is updating itself), to catch this event? Without having to set an interval in order to validate it myself?**

Answer (score 0):

I found this function very useful. But I'm not sure it will trigger the way you want it to.

I found this detects changes made in the inspector (but I read there might be some trouble with pseudo classes due to security reason as you can detect if a link was visited).

Returns one rule like: body{color:red;}

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText;
```

or this will returns all the attached style sheets.

```
var allCSS = 
    [].slice.call(document.styleSheets)
    .reduce(function (prev, styleSheet) {
        if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
            return prev +
                [].slice.call(styleSheet.cssRules)
                    .reduce(function (prev, cssRule) {
                        return prev + cssRule.cssText;
                    }, '');
        } else {
            return prev;
        }
    }, '');
```